ImportError: cannot import name '_get_socket_with_port' from 'torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api'
Появилась необходимость запустить yolo8 на ноутбуке с intel ARC.
При покупке ноутбука обратил внимание на эту статью
Дошёл до шага 2.2, дальше получил ошибку:

ImportError: cannot import name '_get_socket_with_port' from
'torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api'
(/home/sergei/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py)

Использую версии torch и intel_extension_for_pytorch 2.4.0.
Сталкивался ли кто-то с такой проблемой, и как решали?
Ubuntu 22.04
Python 3.10
